# Electrical tape use in laptop

Tags: laptop

Hi just wanted to make sure this was okay. I used electrical tape to tape over the clear plastic that holds the video cable in place to the laptop screen. I was replacing the screen and I was worried about dust getting in the connections. The tape is not directly touching the video cable connections only the clear plastic covering it.

Thanks.

By the way if this is important the laptop is a toshiba satellite C855d

Answer (score 3):

Electrical tape is definitely okay, even if it touches the video cable, and is probably actually what I'd recommend you use. I've used it to fix laptop power supply cables before. I've also use it on 110v house wires even as it does not conduct and is made for the such.

Comment: Thank for the advice. I figured it was okay but wanted to make sure. Replacing laptop screens is super easy and definitely beats the 300 dollars a store tried to charge me !

Comment: Kudos to that, I've replaced a few screens. Glad you got it figured out as not many are willing to try.